# Calculation of Conditional Expectation $\Bbb E[f(X)\mid Y]$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

$\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$and thank you for taking the time to read this. :)

My question is about evaluating $\Bbb E[f(X) \mid Y]$ (a random variable in $Y$). There's plenty online (and in my first year lecture notes) about $\Bbb E[X\mid Y]$ and $\Bbb E[f(X)]$, but not $\Bbb E[f(X)\mid Y]$. I appreciated that if you know the pdf of $f(X)$, then this is easy (set $X^* = f(X)$ and just do normally). Is there some special way that I can do this (similar to the $\Bbb E[f(X)] = \int_\Bbb R f(x)p(x) \, dx$, where $p$ is the pdf - if the pdf exists, of course!)?

For a bit of background, I was trying to show that, for $(X,Y)$ jointly Gaussian,
$$\Cov(f(X),Y) = \Bbb E[f'(X)] \Cov(X,Y)$$
for any "nice" function $f$. I was attempting this using "iterated expectation":
$$\Cov(f(X),Y) = \Bbb E[(f(X) - \mu)(Y - \nu)] = \Bbb E[\Bbb E[(f(X)-\mu)(Y-\nu)\mid Y]] \\
= \Bbb E[(Y-\nu)\Bbb E[f(X) - \mu \mid Y]],$$
then using the fact that we know that $X\mid Y\sim N(\mu + \rho\sigma(Y-\nu)/\tau, \sigma^2(1-\rho^2))$ (with the usual symbol conventions). Unfortunately, I couldn't get anywhere with this. I'm not even sure if this is the right method, as I didn't know how to convert this to using $f(X)$ instead of $X$.

Any help would be most appreciated! Thanks! :)

[PS - if someone with lots of SE-experience thinks that I should make this two questions, please just let me know - they are directly related though! :)]

---

**Update 1:** Consider $Y = aX + bZ$ where $X$ and $Y$ have mean 0 and variance 1 and $Z$ ~ $N(0,1)$ is independent of $X$; so $\Cov(X,Y) = a$, by independences. So
$$\Cov(f(X),Y) = \Cov(f(X),aX + bZ) = a\Cov(f(X),X)$$
as $X$ and $Z$ are independent, so $f(X)$ and $Z$ are also. Further, earlier in the question we showed that
$$\Bbb E[g(R)(R-\mu)] = \sigma^2 \Bbb E[g'(R)]$$
where $g$ is a "nice" function and $R$ ~ $N(\mu,\sigma)$. Applying this, we have, for $g(X) = f(X) - \Bbb E[f(X)]$ and using the fact that X has mean 0 and variance 1, that
$$\Cov(f(X),X) = \Bbb E[g(X)X] =  \Bbb E[g'(X)] = \Bbb E[g'(X)],$$
as required. However, this is only for $Y$ in the form given. I need to consider general $(X,Y)$ jointly Gaussian.

I'm not 100% clear on what 'jointly Gaussian' is - I just used it as having pdf given by
$$p_{X,Y}(x,y) = \exp \left( -{1 \over {2(1-\rho^2)}} \left( \left( {{x - \mu} \over \sigma} \right)^2 ... \right) \right).$$
Is this the right definition?

Comment: I'd consider tackling the original problem via [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables)

Comment: Thank you, I shall try that. To be honest, I should have really thought of that haha! Te question is multipart and there was a similar bit earlier where the derivative came about via integration by parts; I was trying the same again, but I see that a Taylor series should be a good shout. Thanks.

Comment: Taylor series are a dead-end here. Start from $X$ and $Y$ centered with variance $1$, then $Y=aX+bZ$ with $a=\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$, $a^2+b^2=1$, and $Z$ standard normal independent of $X$. What does this tell you about $\mathrm{Cov}(f(X),Y)$?

Comment: I've added in my progress to the question, as it's a bit long for a comment. Thanks for your help, but I still haven't quite got it.